# HP Proliant DL380 Gen9 iLO connectivity

Tags: ip, hp, hp-proliant, remote-access, ilo

I'm trying to install windows on a recently purchased (used) HP Proliant DL380 Gen9 server but I do not have a monitor to connect to the server to guide the installation.

The only way to do it is through ILO, however the server has 2 ethernet built in cards and no dedicated ILO port, I have connected both of them to a network where there is DHCP available, the DHCP is functioning fine because it worked to assign addresses to other Proliant Servers (Gen8) with dedicated ILO ports.

So the question is, is there a away to reset the ethernet cards without a monitor in order to receive an IP address? or is there a way to know what IP addresses assigned to either of those cards? or is there another way all together to access the server ILO management screen?

Comment: Couldn't you just use the monitor you are going to view the iLO on to configure the server initially?

Comment: I don't have a monitor

Comment: if you can't borrow a monitor, you *might*  be able to get a packet capture on each of the ports using wireshark or some equivalent to get some clues about how the ports are configured (for example if they're trying reach an NTP or DNS server,  you should see the source IP in the packets)

Comment: Are you sure you've given us the correct server model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the rear of an HPE ProLiant DL380 Gen9

Are you certain that you're describing the same server model. Any DL380 Gen9 will have an onboard dedicated ILO RJ45 ethernet port.

[image]